# How to create a list of all words in a bunch of files?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, command-line, grep

I'm dealing with a colleague who has made an enormous amount of copied/pasted spelling errors throughout an entire C# solution.

Instead of using a spelling checker on every individual file, I would like to create a list of all words in the entire solution, launch a spelling checker on that list, and do a complete "find-and-replace" for the found entries.

In order to find all words in a file, I had thought of doing something like:

```
grep -wo ".*" blabla.txt
```

But that seems not to be working: instead of showing every individual found word, it still shows the entire lines where the words are found, something like:

```
this is OK
this is NOK
OK it is
NOK it is
Everything is OK
```

While I was expecting something like:

```
this
is
OK
this
is
NOK
...
```

Once I have the list for one file, I can start working with `find ./ -name "*.cs" -exec grep ... {} \; >>output_list` and do some `sort output_list | uniq` in order to get the single words.

But first things first: as `grep -ow ".*"` does not show me the words, but the entire line, what can I do to show all words in a file using UNIX/Linux commandline? (I added `awk` as a tag, because this might be a solution? But I'm certainly no `awk` wizard :-) )

**Edit after first answers:**
`tr` indeed seems the way to go. I might simply use `tr ' ' '\n'`, but there's a catch: I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
find ./ -name "*.cs" -exec cat {} | tr ' ' '\n' >>/mnt/c/Temp_Folder\output.txt \;
```

The command gives me a `>` answer (as I'm inside some code editor or so), what am I still doing wrong?

Comment: You mean "sequences of bytes separated by spaces, tabs and newlines", or *actual* words according to current locale? (The latter would require some hefty Unicode support....) ;-) (Didn't downvote, just pulling your leg a bit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `tr` to replace every space/tab to line break:

```bash
tr '[[:blank:]]' '\n' <file

this
is
OK
this
is
NOK
OK
it
is
NOK
it
is
Everything
is
OK
```

---

Based on your edited question, you may use this `find + tr` solution in `bash` shell:

```bash
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
   tr ' ' '\n' < "$f"
done < <(find . -name '*.cs' -print0) >/mnt/c/Temp_Folder/output.txt
```

Comment: Close but not cigares :-) Can you check the edit of my question?

Comment: You can take out that box of cigars now :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `\w` instead of `.` to identify just word-constituent characters instead of any characters, and use `{2,}` instead of `*` to only look for strings of 2 or more such characters so your output isn't cluttered up with single characters like `a`, `i`, etc.:

```
$ grep -Eow '\w{2,}' file
this
is
OK
this
is
NOK
OK
it
is
NOK
it
is
Everything
is
OK
```

I'd suggest you don't try to find/modify 2-letter "words" either though as they're unlikely to be wrong and are easy to understand when wrong anyway, and stick with words that are 3 or more letters:

```
$ grep -Eow '\w{3,}' file
this
this
NOK
NOK
Everything
```

When you go to replace them, create a file named `bad2good` like this mapping bad to good words:

```
tish this
thsi this
ONK NOK
```

and then use this GNU awk (for `\<` and `\>` word boundaries) script:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        b2g["\\<" $1 "\\>"] = $2
        next
    }
    {
        for ( bad in b2g ) {
            good = b2g[bad]
            gsub(bad,good)
        }
    }
' bad2good file
```

Keep backups and be careful! In particular make sure to do a human review of the files after the changes as well as compiling them as this is a dangerous exercise you're undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` command for that:

```
grep -o -E '\S+' blabla.txt | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Now you will get the output you desired:

```
this
is
OK
this
is
NOK
...
```

Comment: Close but no cigares either :-) Can you also check the edit of my question?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU AWK

```
find ./ -name "*.cs" -print0 | 
    xargs -0 awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
          { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i] } 
          END {
               n=asorti(a,b) 
               for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i]
               print ""
          }
    '
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Able Baker Charlie
Dog Charlie Charlie
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[^[:alpha:]]+"}!arr[$0]++' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Able
Baker
Charlie
Dog
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is one-or-more non-alphabetic characters, then I use array `arr` and post-increment so it is 0 when first seen, greater number otherwise, which I negate to print only 1st occurrence of given line (which is word in this case).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want all unique words in a file, use this:
`cat input.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq`