# Extracting the root of words with awk

Tags: awk, text

I have an awk script that finds word frequencies.

```
{$0 = tolower($0)}  {gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}
```

I work with Turkish text. Turkish words mostly appear with suffixes.

A sample of results from this script:

```
kadınlar       1
kadınlara      1
kadınlarımızın 1
kadınlarına    1
kadınlarının   1
```

Here the root is “kadın” ("woman" in English).

So, “kadınlar” is “women”. “Kadınlara” is “to women” and so on.

Can awk extract the root “kadın” from these 5 words? Do we need to check a dictionary for this?

**Expected output:**

These 5 words with the same root (kadın),

```
kadınlar       1
kadınlara      1
kadınlarımızın 1
kadınlarına    1
kadınlarının   1
```

should be listed as such:

```
kadın 5
```

Comment: If it doesn't understand the Turkish language but instead simply looks for the longest common prefix, how is it going to get "kadın" instead of "kadınlar"?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: do a websearch for "turkish word stemming". awk is probably not the best tool for this. eg. https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-hybrid-Statistical-Approach-to-Stemming-in-An-K%C4%B1%C5%9Fla-Karaoglan/3d28df7e2cfdb03fc020e78823293c76d13b115a

Comment: more concretely: https://snowballstem.org/algorithms/turkish/stemmer.html

Comment: @jhnc Thanks for the links. I didn't know this was such a difficult research area.

Comment: @k314159 I was thinking if it would be possible to check a dictionary. For instance, searching for "kadınlar" also lists "kadın" https://www.seslisozluk.net/kad%C4%B1nlar-nedir-ne-demek/ It looks like this is more like semantic research subject though

Comment: Don't do `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")` as that will create words that didn't originally exist, e.g. it'll change `that'll` into `thatll`. Do `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, " ")` instead to keep words separated. That'll still create new words, of course, e.g. `that'll` will become `that` and `ll` where `ll` obviously isn't a real word that was present in the input, but that's probably preferable (esp if you follow my previous advice to ignore 1-char and 2-char "words") and a consequence choosing to use `gsub()` on punctuation as your starting point.

Comment: My comment above about "my previous advice" was regarding [my answer to another recent question about identifying words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77126993/1745001). Don't try to find common roots of words with awk though, even with a dictionary it'd be a massive can of worms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than writing an awk script, it is probably simpler to use an existing tool.

[snowballstemmer](https://snowballstem.org/) appears to be available for python.

I don't know python but it's easy enough to write something to use it:

```
$ pip install snowballstemmer
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting snowballstemmer
  Downloading snowballstemmer-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 93.0/93.0 KB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: snowballstemmer
Successfully installed snowballstemmer-2.2.0
$ cat >input <<'EOD'
kadınlar
kadınlara
kadınlarımızın
kadınlarına
kadınlarının
EOD
$ cat >tstem <<'EOD'
#!/usr/bin/python3

import snowballstemmer
stemmer = snowballstemmer.stemmer('turkish')

for word in open('input','r').read().splitlines():
    print(word,"->",stemmer.stemWord(word))

EOD
$ chmod +x tstem
$ ./tstem
kadınlar -> kadın
kadınlara -> kadın
kadınlarımızın -> kadın
kadınlarına -> kadın
kadınlarının -> kadın
$
```

---

The most popular stemmer on github seems to be [Turkish Stemmer for Python](https://github.com/otuncelli/turkish-stemmer-python):

```
$ pip install TurkishStemmer
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting TurkishStemmer
  Downloading TurkishStemmer-1.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Installing collected packages: TurkishStemmer
Successfully installed TurkishStemmer-1.3
$ cat >tstem2 <<'EOD'
#!/usr/bin/python3

from TurkishStemmer import TurkishStemmer
stemmer = TurkishStemmer()

for word in open('input','r').read().splitlines()
    print(word,"->",stemmer.stem(word))

EOD
$ chmod +x tstem2
$ ./tstem2
kadınlar -> kat
kadınlara -> kadın
kadınlarımızın -> kadın
kadınlarına -> kadın
kadınlarının -> kadın
$
```

This gets one wrong. (But perhaps it gets some right that snowballstemmer gets wrong?)

---

A sample complete implementation:

```
$ cat >tstem3 <<'EOD'
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import snowballstemmer
stemmer = snowballstemmer.stemmer('turkish')

for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.split():
        print(stemmer.stemWord(word))
EOD
$ chmod +x tstem3
$ <original-input.txt tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
  tr -s '[:punct:]' ' ' |
  ./tstem3 |
  sort |
  uniq -c
      5 kadın
$
```

Comment: `[:upper:]` / `[:;lower:]`  (maybe `[:punct:]` ?) depend on your locale. So do something like `export LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8`, or whatever's appropriate, before running

Comment: I expect all the `tr` stuff can be trivially implemented in python by someone who knows it and understands unicode. The `sort`/`uniq` may still be worth keeping separate if the input corpus could be larger than memory.

Comment: Thanks. I selected your answer. But one of my goals is to learn awk. So, I wonder, if we can do something with awk. How does awk sort these words? We can add all words starting with "k" to an array. Then we can look at the second letter and so on. Once we have "kadın" as the common combination of these 5 sample words we can then truncate the rest of the letters. Do you think this can work at least with trivial cases?

Comment: @zeynel the words in your question have the common leading substring "kadinla", there is no way for awk to know to stop at "kadin" because there is no way for awk to know that "kadin" is a Turkish word while "kadinl" and "kadinla" are not. There is also no way for awk to know whether or not 2 words with a common substring have a common root, e.g. consider "fluffy" and "fluent" - they have a common substring "flu" but even with a dictionary telling you that "flu" is a word, that doesn't mean "flu" is the root of THOSE words, it's totally unrelated.

Comment: If you want to use awk for something to learn awk, you could ask a question about how to find the longest substring of a set of strings - THAT is doable in awk.

Comment: If you can construct the algorithm, there's a good chance it can be implemented in awk. But standard awk [does not even have sort](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort). It's not wrong to want to learn awk by applying it to a problem that motivates you but it is beneficial to know how to solve the problem in the abstract. "Solve problem in awk" is just "Solve problem" if you don't have an algorithm. I don't know python but I could write the code above because I knew I wanted to read a file, split it into lines, etc, and so could search how to do those simpler steps